# How to improve fetching speed from SQL?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, query-performance

I am not expert at MySQL indexes, but I saw a lot of tutorials, still my page takes 7 seconds to load, using PHP.

I have around 50k rows, and 30 columns in MySQL tables.

How can I improve MySQL Fetching data speed? Anything that I can improve in this below query?

```
SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title,tmdb_movies.budget,tmdb_movies.original_language,tmdb_movies.original_title

,translations.translations_english_name

,videos.videos_name,videos.videos_key



FROM tmdb_movies 


LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    translations_tmdb_id
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT translations.translations_english_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS translations_english_name

  FROM translations
  GROUP BY translations_tmdb_id
) translations ON translations.translations_tmdb_id = tmdb_movies.tmdb_id


LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    videos_tmdb_id
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT videos.videos_name) as videos_name
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT videos.videos_key) as videos_key
  FROM videos
  GROUP BY videos_tmdb_id
) videos ON videos.videos_tmdb_id = tmdb_movies.tmdb_id

Where tmdb_movies.tmdb_id= '$tmdb_id'
```

Here, I use `tmdb_id` to connect all tables. `tmdb_id`,`translations_tmdb_id`and `videos_tmdb_id` are indexed in MySQL.

Here is a sample of my MySQL table structure:

**`tmdb_movies` table:**

```
tmdb_id      movie_title
1            Logan
2            Iron Man
3            Superman
```

**`translations` table**

```
translations_tmdb_id      translations_english_name 
1                         English
1                         Hindi
1                         French 
2                         English
2                         Spanish
2                         Hindi
```

**`videos` table**

```
videos_tmdb_id          videos_name
1                       Official Trailer
1                       Trailer 2 
2                       Trailer 1
2                       Trailer 2 HD
3                       Superman Trailer 1
3                       Superman Trailer 2
```

Comment: How long does the query take from the DB directly?

Comment: Please read this, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/   especially the section on query performance, and then [edit] your question. We need to know what indexes you have in place, among other things.

Comment: Do an `EXPLAIN` on the query and add relevant `indexes`

Comment: Your column names are horrible. What does `tmdb` even mean? I'd call a movies table's ID `movie_id` naturally. I'd not call it `tmdb_id` and definitely not `videos_tmdb_id` which makes it sound like some videos ID. Simply `movie_id` in every table and the queries will be much more readable. You should also format your queries better to enhance their readability. And then you should use alias names when working with multiple tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...)`? There are no duplicates.
2. You are only selecting data for one movie. But your derived tables read and aggregate all movies. A great optimizer will look through this and only aggregate records for that one movie. If this were Oracle I would expect exactly this. But with MySQL? I wouldn't rely on this. So add a where clause to your subqueries.
3. You shouldn't select video names and keys without an order by clause. Order them so both have the same order, i.e. the first name matches the first key etc.

Here is your query re-written:

```
SELECT 
  m.movie_title,
  m.budget,
  m.original_language,
  m.original_title,
  t.translations_english_names,
  v.videos_names,
  v.videos_keys
FROM tmdb_movies m
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(translations_english_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS translations_english_names
  FROM translations
  WHERE translations_tmdb_id = @tmdb_id
) t
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(videos_name ORDER BY videos_name) as videos_names,
    GROUP_CONCAT(videos_key ORDER BY videos_name) as videos_keys
  FROM videos
  WHERE videos_tmdb_id = @tmdb_id
) v
WHERE m.tmdb_id = @tmdb_id;
```

And these are the indexes you should use:

```
create index idxm on tmdb_movies(tmdb_id); -- if tmdb_id is PK, you have this already
create index idxt on translations(translations_tmdb_id, translations_english_name);
create index idxv on videos(videos_tmdb_id, videos_name, videos_key);
```

Comment: Perfect, from 7 seconds to 0.00357 seconds seconds. 

Indexes helped me to increase speed by 1-2 seconds, and the improved query worked like magic. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your main `SELECT` statement is probably fine; you're filtering on the autoincrementing primary key.

It's the two subqueries where the opportunities may lie for improving performance.

The first one:

```
  SELECT 
    translations_tmdb_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT translations.translations_english_name 
                  SEPARATOR ', ') AS translations_english_name    
  FROM translations
  GROUP BY translations_tmdb_id
```

A [compound index (sometimes called a composite index or multi-column index)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on `translations_tmdb_id, translations_english_name` has the potential to help this subquery a lot. Why? It can help with both the `GROUP BY` and the `DISTINCT` parts of the query.

The second one:

```
  SELECT 
    videos_tmdb_id
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT videos.videos_name) as videos_name
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT videos.videos_key) as videos_key
  FROM videos
  GROUP BY videos_tmdb_id
```

The same priniciple applies, but the two distinct `DISTINCT` clauses will slow things down a little. Try a compound index on `videos_tmdb_id, videos_name, videos_key`. It should help.

Comment: Please consider offering a comment telling us your results after you try these, or other, things. That way everybody can learn from your experience.

Comment: Sure, I will. By compound index, you mean this query `ALTER TABLE `translations` ADD INDEX( `translations_tmdb_id`, `translations_english_name`);` ??

Comment: Yes, that's a compound index.